# Транзакция не выполянется

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="START TRANSACTION";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql="INSERT INTO  `one`(`name`) VALUES('inden')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql="UPDATE  `two` SET name='OMG_Yoppe' WHERE id=3";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql="UPDATE  `two` SET name='OMG_Ler' WHERE id=3";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sql="COMMIT";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Каждый отдельный запрос выполняется, а через транзакцию нет. Ошибок на экране не выдает.

Comment: А какой движок (engine)? В mysql транзакции вроде только для InnoDB

Comment: преобразовал через ALTER TABLE one ENGINE=InnoDb но результат прежний

Comment: alexlz сделай ответом....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробовал повторить Ваш скрипт. Всё нормально отрабатывает: и insert, и update (тут не знаю, один или два -- результат первого пропадает). Никаких проблем.